# Where is Number of Posts Set?

Tags: templates, blog

I'm hoping someone can help me with this seemingly simple problem.

This is a custom theme that I've been given, and simply changing the number of displayed posts in the Settings menu is ineffective(it's set to 10). But I can't tell where the number of post excerpts being displayed on the blog page is set. It's currently one, with a pagination link at the bottom, but I'm trying to expand it to 5.

The page is: https://community.sum180.com/blog/
The template is:

```
<?php global $post, $wp_query, $blog_query, $shortcode_values, $theLayout; ?>


<section class="content-post-list">
    <ol class="posts-list hfeed">

    <?php
    if (!$blog_query) $blog_query = $wp_query;
    $blogOptions = ($shortcode_values) ? $shortcode_values : $theLayout['blog'];

    while( $blog_query->have_posts() ) : $blog_query->the_post();

        // style and layout info
        $postClass = array();

        // images enabled?
        if ($blogOptions['blog_featured_images']) {

            // class
            $postClass[] = ''; //'style-image-left';

            // get thumbnail image
            $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();

            // image sizes
            $imageW = $blogOptions['image']['width'];
            $imageH = $blogOptions['image']['height'];

            // crop image (default = true)
            $imageCrop = ( $imageW === 0 || $imageH === 0 ) ? false : true; // Setting to FALSE is useful when setting one value so other adjusts automatically

            // get resized image
            // this will return the resized $thumb or placeholder if enabled and no $thumb
            $image = vt_resize( $thumb, '', $imageW, $imageH, $imageCrop );

                // If media field is populated use lightbox for image/video on click
                $popup_link = '';
                if (get_meta('media_url')) {
                    $popup_link = '<a href="'. get_meta('media_url') .'" class="popup" title="'. get_meta('media_title') .'">';
                }
        }

        if (!$image['url']) {
            // no imge
            $postClass[] = 'noImage';
        }

        ?>

        <li class="post-item clearfix">
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class($postClass); ?>>
                <div class="item-container">

                    <?php if ($image['url']) : ?>
                    <div class="the-post-image">
                        <?php
                        if ($popup_link) :
                            echo $popup_link;
                        else : ?>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', THEME_NAME ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>">
                        <?php endif; ?>
                            <figure>
                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" width="<?php echo $image['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $image['height']; ?>" />
                            </figure>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="the-post-content">
                        <header class="entry-header">

                            <?php
                            // Author avatar
                            if ($blogOptions['author_avatar']) :
                                ?>
                                <div class="author-avatar">
                                    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar(  get_the_author_meta('ID'), 35, '', get_the_author_meta('display_name')); ?></a>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                            endif; ?>

                            <!-- Title / Page Headline -->
                            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', THEME_NAME ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                            <?php if ($blogOptions['author_name'] || $blogOptions['post_date'] || $blogOptions['comments_link'] || $blogOptions['category_list']) : ?>
                            <div class="post-header-info clearfix" <?php if ( !$blogOptions['author_avatar'] ) : echo 'style="margin-left: 0;"'; endif; ?>>
                                <?php
                                // Author name
                                if ($blogOptions['author_name']) :
                                    ?>
                                    <address class="vcard author">
                                        <?php _e( 'by ', THEME_NAME ) . the_author_posts_link(); ?>
                                    </address>
                                <?php
                                endif;
                                // Comments link
                                if ($blogOptions['comments_link']) :
                                    // comments link ?>
                                    <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Comment', THEME_NAME ), __( '1', THEME_NAME ), __( '%', THEME_NAME ), '', '' ); ?></span>
                                    <?php
                                endif;
                                // Category list
                                if ($blogOptions['category_list']) :
                                    if ( count( get_the_category() ) ) :
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="cat-links">
                                            <?php
                                            // seperator
                                            if ($blogOptions['post_date']) { echo ' <span class="meta-sep">|</span> '; }
                                            //printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted in</span> %2$s', THEME_NAME ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', get_the_category_list( ', ' ) );
                                            echo get_the_category_list( ', ' );
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                    endif;
                                endif;
                                // Date Published
                                if ($blogOptions['post_date']) :
                                    ?>
                                    <abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time('c'); ?>"><span class="entry-date"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></span></abbr>
                                    <?php
                                    //if ($blogOptions['comments_link']) { echo ' <span class="meta-sep">|</span> '; }  // seperator
                                endif;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </header>

                        <!-- Content -->
                        <div class="entry-content">
                            <?php
                                // Post content/excerpt
                                if ($blogOptions['use_excerpt']) {
                                    if ($blogOptions['excerpt_length'] != '-1')  {
                                        echo customExcerpt(get_the_excerpt(), $blogOptions['excerpt_length']);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    // set $more to 0 or WP will ignore the <!--more--> tags if not on the home page
                                    global $more;
                                    $more = 0;
                                    the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', THEME_NAME ) );
                                }
                                // Read more link
                                if ($blogOptions['read_more'] && $blogOptions['read_more'] != "-1") {
                                    $readMore = prep_content($blogOptions['read_more'], 0, 1);
                                    echo '<div class="read-more"><a href="'. get_permalink() .'" title="'. $readMore .'" class="read-more-link">'. $readMore .'</a></div>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div><!-- END .entry-content -->

                        <!-- Post Footer -->
                        <footer class="post-footer-info">
                            <?php
                            // tag list
                            if ($blogOptions['tag_list']) :
                                $tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', ', ' );
                                if ( $tags_list ):  ?>
                                <div class="tag-links">
                                    <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Tagged</span> %2$s', THEME_NAME ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links', $tags_list ); ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                endif;
                            endif; ?>
                        </footer><!-- END .post-footer-info -->
                    </div>

                </div>
            </article>
        </li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ol>
</section>


<?php

// show paging  (< 1 3 4 >)
if ($blogOptions['paging']) get_pagination($blog_query);

?>
```

Comment: it appears the query is generated somewhere before that template file is loaded.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but what should I be looking for? I've searched the files being called on that page for `$blog_query` and don't see anything that would seem to set that. Which may indicate I need to add it myself. Does this look remotely correct?:
    `$args=array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    ); 
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);`

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a http://para.llel.us/support/ theme. You might start there for docs—for instance, they probably have a custom 'Theme Options' page in the admin.

Short of that, and presuming you're ok with setting it in code (which may negate any future settings in the admin), you'll first need to find out where `$blog_query` is being defined. You can start in `functions.php` but it's hard to say without knowing the theme.

Once you find it, either update its `posts_per_page` value to the value you want or add it manually if it's not there.

Comment: Good eye- that indeed is what it is. It's a client site, and I don't have the license code to get into the forums, however, and the basic "help" pages aren't much use.
`functions.php` didn't have anything, so I'm just going through each page looking for $blog_query.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=5');
$blogOptions = ($shortcode_values) ? $shortcode_values : $theLayout['blog'];
```

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts`, never

Comment: That's what Chris Coyier and Jeff Starr recommend here, also as "Method 2":
https://digwp.com/2009/12/limit-posts-without-plugin/